# Ubuntu 22.04, Dual graphic cards, Intel for display, NVidia for GPGPU, how to setup?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, intel, cuda

My laptop got 2 graphics cards, something very similar to: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu .

I would like to have **Intel** graphic card for display purpose only, and **NVidia** graphic card for heavy computation (GPGPU).

My questions:

1. Do I still need to install NVidia driver? It seems the driver is **for display ONLY** ? So, is it a must to install NVidia driver if I do **NOT** expect to use NVidia card for display ?
2. Without NVidia driver, will those 3rd-party libraries still be able to run? For instance, Tensorflow, etc.? From https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html, it's clearly written that:

> To build an application, a developer has to install only the CUDA
> Toolkit and necessary libraries required for linking.
>
> In order to run a CUDA application, the system should have a CUDA
> enabled GPU and an NVIDIA display driver that is compatible with the
> CUDA Toolkit that was used to build the application itself.

It looks to me:

- In order to run CUDA application, I have to install NVidia Driver, which enables the NVidia graphics card.
- However, the NVidia Driver is for display purpose. In order to use it, I have to use NVidia graphics card for display, rather than using Intel card for display???

Sorry for my naive question. A kind of conceptually confused... Looking forward to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the NVidia graphic card may be used for CUDA computation as long as I do *not* enable it for display.

Answer (score 0):

The `nvidia` driver is needed for any usage of the GPU, while for display you would need to load both the `nvidia_drm` and the `nvidia_modeset`, or at least this is the case on my machine.
Just blacklisting them on boot with a `/etc/modprobe.d/` file prevents the graphic stack to be loaded, but CUDA works just fine.

Indeed this is the trick I use to prevent the `drm` (which is used for display purposes AFAIK) driver to depends on the `nvidia` and, thus, allowing the reload the latter without any dependencies chain when new versions are released.

This is particulary helpful on a server where the display is provided by an integrated BMC and (likely) your GPU comes without any outputs.

Comment: This of course holds until you use the closed-source drivers, I cannot tell how it works for the Nouveau drivers, but I don't think is the case if you need any CUDA capability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a laptop, you have to use the "optimus/prime" technology to do what you want, as is mentioned in the linked article. The nvidia driver decides (with your input) which graphics card to use. You need this because a laptop has only one display output and some kind of coordination between drivers is necessary.

Comment: Where is the link?

Comment: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu